# How to plot a multiindex dataframe having suplots for the first level index?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe, multi-index

I have a pandas multiindex dataframe with quarters 1-4 and hours 0-23 as the index.
The data Looks like this

```
quarter hour    value1  value2  value3
1   0   0.06    0.47    0.50
1   1   0.65    0.04    0.65
1   2   0.58    0.10    0.60
1   3   0.51    0.07    0.17
...

4   20  0.82    0.17    0.96
4   21  0.08    0.98    0.09
4   22  0.73    0.43    0.73
4   23  0.99    0.85    0.42
```

How can I plot 4 linegraphs as subplots in a 2x2 arrangement having Q1 and Q4 on the top and Q2 and Q3 on the bottom?

I have been trying with

```
    f,  ((ax1, ax4), (ax2, ax3)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex='col', sharey='row')
    ax1.plot(df.loc[1])
```

But it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: what do you mean 'it doesnt seem to work'?
Is it the layout that doesnt work (it should) or is it not the right data that's plotted?

You have to provide more information about your problem

Comment: The "get_loc" returns "KeyError: 1" from "Python 2.7.6.1\App\lib\site-packages\pandas\tseries\index.py 1178". Even when I try ax1.plot(df) it does not plot anything.

Comment: are you sure your index is an `int` and not a `str`. if its a str you need to refer to it as `df.loc['1']`

Comment: oops, sorry. You are right. With the string it worked.   Thanks a lot for your help.